# C# Clearing the columns in a datagridview also removes al the rows?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Does it makes sense that when columns of a datagridview are cleared, all rows are removed?

Comment: Why not? How rows can be present if columns information is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a table display such a s DataGridView, if there are no columns, there cannot be any rows, and vice versa.

Comment: First I was somewhat surprised that all my rows were gone after clearing the columns. But when I think about it, it does makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are removing all of the columns, then there can be no rows associated with them.  You'd need at least one column in order to have rows.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just toggle visibility on the column instead?

```
dgv.Columns[sColumnName].Visible
```